# Проверка пользователя на участие в группе для Facebook, Instagram, Vkontakte

Tags: javascript, php

Как можно реализовать на сайте проверку пользователя на участие в группе в Instagram, Facebook, Vkontakte? Суть задачи: человек выбирает на сайте социальную сеть (Instagram или Facebook или Vkontakte), вводит свое имя (ID, user name). После чего должен придти положительный или отрицательный ответ о состоянии подписки в группе.

Answer (score 0):

На примере вк

Пользователь разрешает вашему приложению доступ в к профилю
Дальше по клику вызываете этот метод
https://vk.com/dev/groups.isMember

Возможно прокатит и без его входа, потому что в спецификации написано, что можно использовать и ключ сообщества